# Authenticating user in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC and the User.Identity that comes with it.

I've just gotten the login functionality done on my site, but I'm missing something.

after the authentication.SignIn(identity), the isAuthenticated flag of the User.Identity object is false, and the isAnonymous flag is true.

here's the code I'm using. let me know what I've missed.

```
ClaimsIdentity identity =
                            new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                            {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)});
                        IOwinContext ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();

                        IAuthenticationManager authManager = ctx.Authentication;

                        authManager.SignIn(identity);

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: and also. is there a way to set the userId in the Identity object?

Comment: I would recommend walking through an ASP.Net Identity 2 tutorial.  It's a complex topic to cover here.  Entire books could be written on the subject of web authentication.

Comment: Basically though, the SignIn Function in the IAuthenticationManager is where a users credentials are checked, and if correct, claims are added to their user entity for the current request for that user.  Those claims indicate whether a user is authenticated or not.  IsAuthenticated is based on the persence of a claim called "IsAuthenticated" of a specific type, if it's not in the users claims array, they won't show as Authenticated.  In that same place is where you could add other claim types you create on your own, like a User ID.  However it has a UserID claim by default if I recall.